# Visual Studio 2015 - ClickOnce Build and Deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, clickonce

myApplication.application file placement...

How do I control the placement of this file for deployment?

When I publish from Visual Studio GUI, the VS GUI nests the .application file with the rest of the binary files.

When I publish from the command line with MSBuild, the MSBuild stores the .application file with the setup.exe two levels up:

```
-------------
Visual Studio ClickOnce Build and Publish
-------------
MyApplication
--Setup.exe
--Application Files
----MyApplication_01.01.01.01
------myapplication.exe
------MyApplication.application <-- why here?



-------------
Command Line MSBuild.exe Build and Publish
-------------
MyApplication
--Setup.exe
--MyApplication.application  <-- why here?
--Application Files
----MyApplication_01.01.01.01
------myapplication.exe
```

There must be some way to control the placement of this file?  I have no idea how to do that.  There must be a command line switch to invoke or something?

Comment: When I publish from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 GUI, the .application file is stored with the setup.exe at the same level up. Just like the result of MSBuild command line. How did you published from Visual Studio GUI? Have you set any other option?

Comment: Same inputs as far as I can see.

Comment: What does you mean "Same inputs as far as I can see"? Could you please try to create a new application project without any modification, then use clickonce publish to publish this project, check the placement of this .application file? If this issue is still persist, please share us more detail steps so that we could reproduce this issue or provide a sample video about it. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 GUI creates two copies and places them in both folders. Command line just in top level. The question is how to force MsBuild from command line to do the same as VS2015 GUI?